# Updating Database in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am updating a record in `Sqlite` database through the function given below.Their is only 1 Table and a number of columns.Initially i am updating 3 columns. Problem i am facing :

1) The Problem is that in `Logcat` initial data is shown but updated data is not showing. Also `Logcat` not showing any error.

2) When i am displaying in `Toast` only last value which i added in database statically is showing. Initial two are not present in Toast.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ContractSqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "thorcontract_Db";

    // TABLE NAME
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contract";
    // COLUMN
    private static final String PRIMARY_COLUMN = "heading";
    private static final String CONTRACT_TITLES_TITLE = "cnttitle";
    private static final String CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE = "cntSUBTITLE";
    private static final String CONTRACT_TITLES_BIDID = "cntbidid";
    private static final String LOADSUMMARY_HEADER = "lsheader";
    private static final String LOADSUMMARY_FOOTER = "lsfooter";
    private static final String SECTION1_TITLE = "s1title";
    private static final String SECTION1_BODY = "s1body";
    private static final String SECTION2_TITLE = "s2title";
    private static final String SECTION2_BODY = "s2body";
    private static final String SECTION3_TITLE = "s3title";
    private static final String SECTION3_BODY = "s3body";
    private static final String SECTION4_TITLE = "s4title";
    private static final String SECTION4_BODY = "s4body";
    private static final String SECTION5_TITLE = "s5title";
    private static final String SECTION5_BODY = "s5body";
    private static final String SECTION6_TITLE = "s6title";
    private static final String SECTION6_BODY = "s6body";
    private static final String SECTION7_TITLE = "s7title";
    private static final String SECTION7_BODY = "s7body";
    private static final String SECTION8_TITLE = "s8title";
    private static final String SECTION8_BODY = "s8body";
    private static final String SECTION9_TITLE = "s9title";
    private static final String SECTION9_BODY = "s9body";
private String title = null, subtitle = null, bidid = null;
    public ContractSqlite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_CONTRACT_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + PRIMARY_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"

                + CONTRACT_TITLES_TITLE + " TEXT ," + CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE
                + " TEXT ," + CONTRACT_TITLES_BIDID + " TEXT,"
                + LOADSUMMARY_HEADER + " TEXT," + LOADSUMMARY_FOOTER + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION1_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION1_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION2_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION2_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION3_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION3_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION4_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION4_BODY + " TEXT,"

                + SECTION5_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION5_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION6_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION6_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION7_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION7_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION8_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION8_BODY + " TEXT,"
                + SECTION9_TITLE + " TEXT," + SECTION9_BODY + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTRACT_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addRecord(String title, String subtitle, String bidid) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // String title1 = title;
        // String subtitle1 = subtitle;
        // String bidid1 = bidid;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        try {

            values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_TITLE, title);

            values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE, subtitle);
            values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_BIDID, bidid);

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Log.i("Initial Data", " " + title + " " + subtitle +  " " + bidid);
            db.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            db.close();
        }

    }

    public String[] getrecord() {

        String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            title = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CONTRACT_TITLES_TITLE));
            subtitle = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE));
            bidid = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CONTRACT_TITLES_BIDID));
            // Dumps "Title: Test Title Content: Test Content"
            Log.i("CONTRACTTITLES", "Title: " + title + " Content: " + subtitle);

            cursor.close();
        }
        return new String[] { title, subtitle, bidid };

    }

    public int update(String title, String subtitle, String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_TITLE, title);
        values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE, subtitle);

        values.put(CONTRACT_TITLES_SUBTITLE, id);

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, PRIMARY_COLUMN + " =?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(1) });

    }
}
```

Method Calling From Main Activity.

csq is database class object

for adding a record

```
csq.addRecord("abc", "xyz", "1234");
```

for updating

```
csq.update(cnttitle_str, cntsubtitle_str, cntbid_str);
```

for getting a record

```
String[] str = csq.getrecord();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
    " " + str[0] + " " + str[1] + "" + str[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: please check my answer , and if this is useful , vote up

Answer (score 0):

Updated data is not showing because you don't have a `Log` line there (if I understand you correctly).

You only get one line because you need to iterate through the `Cursor` and return a list or some such.

Answer (score 0):

this sulotion is :
if you want to see all record , do this in your Database class :

```
public void showAllDBcells() {

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DB;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

        Log.d("your tag",cursor.getString(0));
        Log.d("your tag",cursor.getString(1));
        Log.d("your tag",cursor.getString(2));
        // and for another data , just extends code for 3 4 5 ... columns

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

//
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

}

you can call method in your **activity** , and see your stored data from Database in Logcat .